# 'expression' argument of security function should have no side effects

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to put a trendline indicator in a sceener. The problem is that it is not possible to draw a line in a security call but paradoxically I need to draw this line because I use `line.get_price` to get the signal for the breakout.

```
I get this error: 'expression' argument of security function should have no side effects.
```

Is there a solution to this problem?

Here is the summary of the code:

```
screenerFunc() =>
line1 := line.new(bar_index - triangle_h_x1, hdot1, bar_index - triangle_h_x2, triangle_h_y2, color=col_red, width=2, extend=extend.right)
line2 := line.new(bar_index - triangle_l_x1, ldot1, bar_index - triangle_l_x2, triangle_l_y2, color=col_green, width=2, extend=extend.right)

isTrueTop = 0 
isTrueBot = 0 
if barstate.islast 
    if close > line.get_price(line1, bar_index) 
        isTrueTop := 1 
        
    if close < line.get_price(line2, bar_index) 
        isTrueBot := 1 

[isTrueTop, isTrueBot] = screenerFunc()

[isTrueTop, isTrueBot]   = security(t1,   timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `line.get_price()` in a screener function, like you've tried to do. But you can use `line.get_x1()` and `line.get_y1()` instead:

```
[isTrueTop, isTrueBot] = security(t1, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())

screenerFunc() =&gt;
    line1 := line.new(bar_index - triangle_h_x1, hdot1, bar_index - triangle_h_x2, triangle_h_y2, color=col_red, width=2, extend=extend.right)
    line2 := line.new(bar_index - triangle_l_x1, ldot1, bar_index - triangle_l_x2, triangle_l_y2, color=col_green, width=2, extend=extend.right)

    isTrueTop = 0
    isTrueBot = 0
    if barstate.islast
        if close &gt; line.get_y
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I can't get it to work.. I have an error with &gt